# Sessions in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

i have a login page so once the user enters the correct details he enters into the home page. Now i want to implement 3 things

1. once he clicks the button 'log out' he must be redirected to a page saying" logged out successfully " n even if clicks the back button in the browser, he should not be able to access.
2. if the user leaves the homepage idle for a specific amount of time say 10minutes and then he tries to navigate after 10 mins a msg should display saying "Your Session has been expired login again"
3. if given the url of homepage he shouldnt be able to access unless logged in.
   I am not sure about what exactly i need to do and how to do. Plz Help
   Regards

Indranil Mutsuddy

Comment: i me new to asp.net i did the designing n coding(still in progress)
but nothing much regarding the sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generally use ASP.NET [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) for this.

- When the Log Out button is clicked, call FormsAuthentication.SignOut.  This will remove the forms-authentication ticket information from the cookie (or URL if cookieless).
- For a timeout, use the timeout attribute in the system.web/authentication/forms element of your web.config.  Note that your forms authentication timeout is independent of your Session timeout.

Answer (score 2):

1) When the user logs out of the system I would recommend doing a Session.Abandon(). If the user clicks the Back button in the browser he might see the cached version of the old page (this is entirely browser dependant), but he won't be able to do anything anyway.
Disable the caching in your pages and the user shouldn't even see the cached old version :)
A simple way to do this would be to add the following into Global.asax's `Application_BeginRequest`:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

2) In your web.config set the session lifetim to 10 minutes, incremental.. That will do the trick

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms defaultUrl="~/LoggedIn.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10"/>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

3) You can do this using authorization rules in web.config. If you want no anonymous users to access your website just enable access only to logged in users like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

If you want to restrict access not to the whole website, but only to some areas (like the MyAccount area, then you can add this instead.. Note: Web.config can have multiple `<location>` elements!

```
  <location path="MyAccountFolder">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

There's one important note about the location tag. The Path does NOW start with a '/'! So if you want to secure the /MyAccount folder, then your tag will start like this:

```
<location path="MyAccount" />
```

Comment: hi thanks 4 ur reply.
I tried this on page_load event(pages thatcan be viewed after logged in only) if(session["UserId"]==Null) response.redirect("login.aspx")
on login page i've session["UserId"]=txtBox1.text

and somehow it works..
Is it the correct way?

Comment: Not really.. If you add the code from points 2) and 3) to your web.config then if an anonymous user accesses a page in your website and is not logged in - he will be automagically redirected to ~/Login.aspx. When he successfully logs in - he'll be redirected to ~/LoggedIn.aspx. As you can see this is completely transparent and configurable, no extra code needed in every page :)

Comment: added another example in the bottom of the answer.. Don't forget to "accept" the answer if it answers your question ;)

Comment: Hi Artiom
I did exactly the way u mentioned, but this i m facing problems like.
1. after logging out(session.abandon()at its load event) when i click the back button it does goes inside and works as never logged out(i included the cache code, code #2and #3 as u said).
2. After including the 'no cache' code my login page takes way too time(as it has pics slides ) and sometimes the css doesnt even load.
3. Suppose i opened my login in Moz after logging in i copied the home url so when i log out and paste the url, the page does open w/o err

Comment: 4.When time elapse and i reload the page, it gets redirected to login page but the images and css are disordered.

P.S I uploaded my project at the following link
http://www.4shared.com/file/ahtJUNN3/MyModifiedDesign20Apr.html
plz have a look.
I have not included the codes related to sessions and stuff there.
Thanks a lot again.

Comment: If you click the Back button, the browser will load the cached version of the page. in some cases, the browser will even ignore the no-cache headers. This doesn't mean that the page will work though. If you click refresh at this point, you will be thrown to the login page. So this is now a security issue at all.

Comment: I would recommend removing the caching code. This way your pages will load faster, be cached, but the website will still be secure, so you don't have to worry :)
If the user isn't redirected to the login page (from what you said in 1. and 3.) you didn't correctly set up the authorization rules from my third snippet.. Please check your configuration again. (I added a note in the bottom of the post about it!)

Comment: thax 4 d quick reply...i tired to put all the secure pages into a folder but that also was showingsome parsing error...and about things u ,mentioned now i'll cross-check n let u know. 
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

***Case 1:***

When clicked on the log off button clear the Session.

Clicking the back button in the browser might result in fetching the page from the cache. So by cheking Session in the page might not be effective. You can disable caching for the page so that when back button is clicked a new request to the page will be generated.

For pages not to be cached set this

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

***Case 2:***

You can set the default timeout for Session as 10 minutes. See **[HttpSessionState.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx)**

***Case 3:***

Check Session for null and if found to be null then redirect to a login page.

Comment: Thanks Rahul
Can u give a brief about disabling the caching.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`

Comment: Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
This code works fine in IE but not in Moz.
Any suggestions.